# Cross table query on a single queston

Tags: sql

Here's a table

```
   A    B   C   D   R
  'a'   1   3   1   0
  'a'   2   3   1   1
  'a'   2   3   1   0
  'b'   1   3   1   1
  'b'   2   4   3   2
  'b'   1   4   3   0
  'c'   2   4   3   0
```

The cross tabulation of R with respect to A is as follows:

```
     A  R   count

     a  0   2
     a  1   1
     a  2   0
     b  0   1
     b  1   1
     b  2   1
     c  0   1
     c  1   0
     c  2   0
```

The cross tabulation gives the frequency of R's value depending on A.

What is the sql query for this operation?

Comment: Have you tried writing any query yet ?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. i've removed the conflicting tags, however, please update your post and tag only the correct RDBMS for what you're using.

Comment: @Sudipta Mondal yes , i am trying it but cannot find a way to count A and R , My idea is to count A and R's row and store count and A in a new table, then select unique R  and then cross with the newly formed table , i am struck in the first phase.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i mean , will it make a difference , sql querry will always remain the same , i think, correct me if i am wrong please.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `CROSS JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`

```
select ta.a, tr.r, count(t.a) 
from (select distinct a from tab) TA
cross join (select distinct r from tab) TR
left join tab t on t.a = ta.a and t.r = tr.r
group by ta.a, tr.r
```

Comment: could you explain please what is ta and tr ?

Comment: `ta` and `tr` are table aliases. You can imagine that the result of a subquery is a table and the name of the table is `ta` and `tr`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Using CROSS JOIN and a conditional sum to achieve the count:

```
  declare @Table table (A char(1), B int, C int, D int, R int)
  Insert into @Table values
   ('a', 1, 3, 1, 0)
  , ('a', 2, 3, 1, 1)
  , ('a', 2, 3, 1, 0)
  , ('b', 1, 3, 1, 1)
  , ('b', 2, 4, 3, 2)
  , ('b', 1, 4, 3, 0)
  , ('c', 2, 4, 3, 0)

  select A, x.R, Sum(iif(x.r = t.R, 1, 0))
  from @Table t
  cross join (Select distinct R from @Table) x
  group by A, x.R
  order by a, x.R
```